# Can having native mobile app for your website reduce server load?

Tags: optimization, mobile-devices

Sorry guys, I'm a bit new to this. I'm not sure if I'm asking the right questions here. I'm creating an iPhone app for my website, and most of my users are going to use it through the iPhone rather than the website. I was wondering, is that a good thing for the servers or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the size of the data, and who does the pagination if any. Large amounts of data being sent to a thick client will result in more traffic, whereas pagination in a website can reduce it since probably not all data will have to be sent before the user finds what they are looking for.